# React Native broadcast and discover nearby devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

First off: This is more of a logical question than a code-specific question.

I am trying to create a view similar to the [iOS AirDrop view](https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/original/13/97/63704919843830/0/637049198438301397.jpg) where users can see other users. This means, every user needs to broadcast/advertise their custom username, which can be seen by all other nearby users that scan the area.

I have tried using `react-native-ble-plx`, since I read [on the Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111829) that iPhones can act as BLE (bluetooth low energy) peripherals. (Also, I read that newer Android devices support this as well)

I've tried the following:

```js
import ble, { BleManager, Characteristic } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
// ...
const bleManager = new BleManager();
bleManager.startDeviceScan(null, null, async (e, d) => {
    if (e) console.log(`BT Error: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
    if (d && d.id && d.isConnectable) {
        console.log(`Connecting to: ${d.id} ('${d.name}')...`);
        const device = await d.connect();

        const services = await device.services();
        console.log('services: ', services.join(', '));
        const characteristic = await device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(BLE_SERVICE_UUID, BLE_SERVICE_UUID, '123');
        console.log(`Characteristics: ${JSON.stringify(characteristic)}`);
    }
});
```

But I haven't found a way to broadcast a value which others can read, is that even possible with BLE?

I've also looked into beacons (specifically [react-native-beacons-manager](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager)), but I'm not sure if that is what I want since an Android/iOS phone is not a 'beacon'..

So my question is: Are there technologies/libraries that allow broadcasting of a message (my custom username) which others can see? Ideally I want to communicate between them, like exchanging a token, but that's not a requirement.

I'd appreciate any help or pointings into the right direction here, thanks!

Comment: You can't broadcast a value. You would need to actually connect to the peripheral and read the value from a characteristic

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually it does work. See my answer for details. (I think under the hood the API still searches for peers and connects to those, it does broadcast pairing codes though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working after really long debugging nights.

It is possible using the Google Nearby Messages API, and setting it to use .BLE only.

I've created an open source react native module for this here: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-google-nearby-messages

Comment: and how do you do this on iOS devices?

Comment: From ios to android communication never happens

Comment: That's completely wrong. You can communicate from iOS <-> Android without problems. The library I developed uses GNM API which works on iOS and Android.